# Always a 401 res in useOpenWeather() - react-open-weather lib

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add weather widget to my react app, I'm trying to use React-Open-Weather lib. But the function that fetches the data `useOpenWeather()` always responses with a `401`, I've confirmed my api-key is valid by putting it in the URL that is given in the documentation of react-open-weather. But I don't know what is wrong
`

> Error: GET [http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?appid={apikey}&lang=en&units=metric&lat=48.137154&lon=11.576124](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?appid=%7Bapikey%7D&lang=en&units=metric&lat=48.137154&lon=11.576124) 401 (Unauthorized)

**My Code**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactWeather, { useOpenWeather } from 'react-open-weather';

const Weather = (props) => {
    const { data, isLoading, errorMessage } = useOpenWeather({
        key: 'myapikey',
        lat: '48.137154',
        lon: '11.576124',
        lang: 'en',
        unit: 'metric', // values are (metric, standard, imperial)
    });


    return (
        <div>
            <ReactWeather
                isLoading={isLoading}
                errorMessage={errorMessage}
                data={data}
                lang="en"
                locationLabel="Munich"
                unitsLabels={{ temperature: 'C', windSpeed: 'Km/h' }}
                showForecast
            />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Weather
```

I tried re-installing the React-Open-Weather lib but that doesn't fix the problem

The URL that I used to confirm my api key: [http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&appid={apikey}](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&appid=%7Bapikey%7D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-api, `onecall` returns all possible functions:

> The One Call API 2.5 provides the following weather data for any geographical coordinates:

- Current weather
- Minute forecast for 1 hour
- Hourly forecast for 48 hours
- Daily forecast for 7 days
- National weather alerts
- Historical weather data for the previous 5 days

Some of the features, like forecast, are not allowed for free accounts.
By running `weather` instead of `onecall`, you only get the current weather:

```
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&appid={API key}
```

and with your parameters, it displays the data correctly.

Comment: Thanks but it's not a simple fetch req, the function `useOpenWeather()` is making the call so what can I do??

Comment: @QuietCoder You could use another weather provider supported by the library like WeatherBit or fork the code and modify the backend so it will ignore the forecast code (you'll also have to remove the showForecast in your own code). 

It's actually a reported issue on GitHub: https://github.com/farahat80/react-open-weather/issues/15 but it looks like it didn't get fixed.

Comment: Also, you might want to redact your API keys... Even though it's the free plan, these can still be rate limited or your openweathermap account could be shut down if it's used for spam.

Comment: Thanks, I was gonna remove it but forgot, thanks for the reminder